# Using SPO and trying to create a conditional column based on a blank value in another

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

First of all, I have no experience with JSON so there is that learning curve but I am trying to create a conditional format in one column based off a blank value in another.

The other column also happens to be a lookup column.

Comment: What exactly you want to do conditionally? Do you want to color the column based on another column OR you want to display some value based on another column? Can you edit your question & add all possible conditions (in words) as per your requirements?

Comment: I wanted to fill the Department column based on the POC (Lookup) column with a color to identify those departments that have not identified someone one to assist in the work effort.

Comment: Check my answer given below. It should help you to get started with.

Answer (score 0):

You can show the column value conditionally based on another lookup column in list like:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if([$ParentLookup.lookupValue] == 'Parent 1', 'Child of Parent 1', '')"
}
```

Where `ParentLookup` is internal name of lookup column. You can get the correct internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Output**:

[image]

You can also apply conditional color to text like:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if([$ParentLookup.lookupValue] == 'Parent 1', 'Child of Parent 1', '')",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if([$ParentLookup.lookupValue] == 'Parent 1', 'green', 'red')"
  }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

---

> The lookup field object has the following properties (with example values):
>
> ```
> {
>    "lookupId": "100",
>    "lookupValue": "North America",
> }
> ```

**Microsoft documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

You can refer above documentation for syntax & complex scenarios/conditions in JSON.